# Does MySQL SELECT * with a LIMIT 1 return FALSE on no results?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a database wrapper class and every now and then the server goes away... Typical 2006 error message for MySQL. I've wrapped logic around handling reconnecting to the database and that seems to be working. What's interesting to me is that this query:

```
SELECT id FROM pixel WHERE (id = 522574) AND (advertiser_entity_id = 45574) LIMIT 1
```

Executing that line in PHPMYADMIN yields an empty set. Executing that via the database class returns false.

Has anyone seen this behavior? No mysql_errorno or error messages are coming back.

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $this->database_connection); 
if (false === $result) { 
// handle error here 
} 
else { return $result; }
```

Comment: It's very likely that you've made a mistake in your database class since functions like mysql_query always returns a MySQL Result, even if there are no results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't an error to not find a matching row. If it doesn't find any records that meet your WHERE conditions, that's not an error, it just returns an empty result. If you're writing your own DB layer, it also shouldn't treat it as an error - the query was run just fine, it just didn't find any matches.

If you're asking, though, why your code returns false, it's probably just because usually languages treat a zero or null value as "false" in a boolean context.

Comment: Thanks Mike. So the response from MySQL is a boolean(FALSE). I thought it should return an empty set though... the mysql_query api documentation says it will return false only in the case of an error. Further, I updated my question with my code.

Comment: I don't do PHP much, but based on your comment to your question, I'd just check mysql_errorno() to see if there was an error instead of the result object. I'm not primarily a PHP guy though, so if someone with a more detailed background with PHP's MySQL library disagrees with me, go with what they say.